# Range("").Value = "Percentage%" Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a simple line of VBA that erases certain cells when other cells equals a certain value.

The following code works great with Text and Numeric value, but it fails to check and clear the cells if the value equals a percentage.

```
Sub Module1()

 If Range("C5").Value Like "Done" And Range("D5").Value = "100%" Then
    Range("B5").ClearContents
 End If


End Sub
```

It still doesn't work if I remove the % sign from the D5 Value checkup. The cell itself is Formatted as a Percentage.

Comment: A percentage is a number formated like text.  Change `Range("D5").Value = "100%" ` to `Range("D5").Value = 1`

Comment: The cell which is formatted as percentage still holds some value try `And Range("D5").Value = 1 Then`

Comment: Try `Range("D5").Text = "100%"`

Comment: Thanks all :)
Scott's solution worked perfectly!
If you could post this as an answer so I can close it up, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Posted as answer so it can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A percentage is a number formatted like text.

Change

```
Range("D5").Value = "100%"
```

to its decimal value.

```
Range("D5").Value = 1
```